# Angular won't call controller constructor at all, although state transition is successful

Tags: angularjs

I've got a module, whose controller is not called at all:

```
import angular from "angular";

var ToolResource = require("workflow/tool/tool.service");

class ToolListController {

    // @ngInject
    construtor($location, $stateParams, $state, tools) {
        console.log("ToolListController called");

        this.$location = $location;
        this.$state = $state;
        this.$stateParams = $stateParams;

        this.tools = tools;
    }
}

// @ngInject
function routesList($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("tool-list", {
        url: "/tool",
        parent: "layout",
        templateUrl: "/app/workflow/tool/toolList.html",
        controller: "ToolListController",
        controllerAs: "vm",
        data: {
            pageTitle: "Tool",
            pageDesc: "List of tools, available for workflow construction."
        },
        resolve: {
            ToolResource: "ToolResource",
            tools: function(ToolResource) {
                return ToolResource.query().$promise;
            }
        }
    });
}

module.exports = angular.module("tool", [])
  .service ('ToolResource', ToolResource)
  .controller('ToolListController', ToolListController)
  .config(routesList);
```

Angular successfully switches to the respective state, but just doesn't initialize the controller (for instance, it doesn't print the message `ToolListController called`). I didn't forget to inject tool module into the main module.

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class constructor needs to be spelled `constructor`, not `construtor`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I started suspecting something awful like this, re-written the module from scratch and voila - it worked. Was about to go to church and light a candle for Igor Minar, but you explained the magic. Sorry for wasting your time.